# How do I determine a View transition at the time of transition, or dynamically?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to build a Tab-Like view in SwiftUI, where sections are transitioned left or right relative to their positioning in the list. I know that `TabView` Exists, but I'd prefer to not animate back and forth over ALL the child views; just to animate the incoming and outgoing views in a tab-like fashion.

I'm getting stuck on a way to define the transition, since at the time of rendering the view tree I don't know if the current view will need to exit left or right, since the next section has not been selected by the user yet.

It seems like I need a way to override the current views removal transition when `selectedSection` (below) is changed, but before the tree is redrawn..

Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
enum Section: String, CaseIterable {
    case one, two, three, four
}

struct Demo: View {
    @State var selectedSection: Section = .one

     var body: some View {
            let transition: AnyTransition = .asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .leading), removal: .move(edge: .trailing))

          Group {
               switch selectedSection {
               case .one:
                     ViewOne()
                case .two:
                     ViewTwo()
                case .three:
                     ViewThree()
                case .four:
                     ViewFour()
               }
          }
          .transition(transition)
          .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.30), value: selectedSection)
    }
}
```